# Spark SQL `sampleBy` function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The Spark DataFrame class has a [sampleBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy.html) method which can perform stratified sampling on a column given a dictionary of weights, with the keys corresponding to values in the given column. Is there an equivalent way to do this sampling using raw Spark SQL?

Comment: Hi @krasnaya, I think this is quite tricky using raw SparkSQL. I am curious what the restriction is that requires a pure SQL solution? Would you be open to a Python + SQL solution?

Comment: What do you mean by Python + SQL? Like writing Pyspark? Generally I prefer writing plain SQL due to it's simplicity, avoiding the need to bundle libraries and package code etc.

Comment: Ah ok yeah that's what I meant and figured. I don't know immediately how to do that.